# How to perform an action when clicking a button inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, fragment, android-context

Inside my fragment I have a button and when I press the button, I want to perform a call.

However,when I click the button, nothing seems to happen, what am I doing wrong here ?

This is my fragment code :

```
package fr.aitec_informatique.aitecinformatiques;


import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    Button dial;

    private Context mContext;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        v.findViewById(R.id.dial);

        return v;
    }
    public void onDialButton(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:xxxxxxxxxx"));

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working ? You are not able to call when you press the button ?

Comment: yes that's it, and it works when I'm in a blank application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the `Button` like this:

```
dial = v.findViewById(R.id.dial);
```

It happens maybe you didn't define the `Button` well. `getActivity()` works actually.

Also, `onDialButton` never used. Instead, add a listener to the `Button` then call the `onDialButton`:

```
dial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

      onDialButton();
    }
});
```

**Update:**

You should be using `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission` nowadays:

```
public void onDialButton() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Permission is not granted
    }
    // first check for the permission

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:xxxxxxxxxx"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And just call `onDialButton()` in your `onClick()`.

Read the documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java

Comment: Hi, I tried the method but there is no change, I do not know if I wrote the code well here it is:<!-- language: lang-js --> dial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
onDialButton();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); intent.setData((Uri.parse("tel:0606802080")));

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    return;
                }
            }
        });

Comment: Check the updated answer. No need to use the same code twice.

Comment: Good since I can not make it work I will create more activity instead of fragment

Comment: That's your choice. However, you could do that with two different queries. Please consider accepting one of the answers which helped you and made the issue clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using a normal `OnClickListener`.

Try this:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

Button dial;

private Context mContext;

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    dial = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.dial);
      //I think dial is the id of your button

    dial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onDialButton();
    }
});

    return v;
}
public void onDialButton() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:xxxxxxxxxx"));

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    startActivity(intent);
 }
}
```

Comment: I started to write the answer before you. My answer is longer, that's why I posted it after you.

Comment: It was not intention to send a duplicate.

Comment: It's alright. However, in the new versions of Android Studio, there is no need for `(Button)` when initializing a widget like now.

Comment: Good since I can not make it work I will create more activity instead of fragment